# SQL CTE To Get Hierarchy as concatenated result

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below example I am trying to retrieve the complete reporting structure of each employees.

For example 1 is reporting to 10.
10 is reporting to 100.
100 is reporting to 1000.
1000 is reporting to 10000.
10000 is reporting to CEO
CEO is reporting to No More Level

so for person 1 the complete reporting structure shoule be |10|100|1000|10000|CEO|No More Level|

Like this I require the complete reporting structure for all persons.

My Data

```
Person  AssignedTo
1   10
2   20
3   30
10  100
20  200
30  300
100 1000
200 2000
300 3000
1000    10000
2000    20000
3000    30000
10000   CEO
20000   CEO
30000   CEO
CEO No More Level
```

Expected Result

```
|10|100|1000|10000|CEO|No More Level|
|20|200|2000|20000|CEO|No More Level|
|30|300|3000|30000|CEO|No More Level|
|100|1000|10000|CEO|No More Level|
|200|2000|20000|CEO|No More Level|
|300|3000|30000|CEO|No More Level|
|1000|10000|CEO|No More Level|
|2000|20000|CEO|No More Level|
|3000|30000|CEO|No More Level|
|10000|CEO|No More Level|
|20000|CEO|No More Level|
|30000|CEO|No More Level|
|CEO|No More Level|
|CEO|No More Level|
|CEO|No More Level|
|No More Level|
```

[image]

I tried this but it is not working.
[SQLFiddleLink](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/44b93/6/0)

> Insert Table statement

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblHierarchy](
    [Person] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AssignedTo] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'1', N'10')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'2', N'20')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'3', N'30')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'10', N'100')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'20', N'200')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'30', N'300')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'100', N'1000')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'200', N'2000')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'300', N'3000')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'1000', N'10000')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'2000', N'20000')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'3000', N'30000')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'10000', N'CEO')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'20000', N'CEO')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'30000', N'CEO')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblHierarchy] ([Person], [AssignedTo]) VALUES (N'CEO', N'No More Level')
GO
```

> My SQL Attempt

```
    with cte as (
    select Person, cast(Person as nvarchar(max)) caption, 
    AssignedTo from tblHierarchy 
    union all 
    select t.Person, cast('|'+ c.caption + '|' + t.Person as nvarchar(max))+'|', t.AssignedTo
    from cte c
    inner join tblHierarchy t on t.AssignedTo = c.Person
)
select Person,caption from cte order by Person
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a filter in first of cte

**Query 1**:

```
 with cte as (
    select Person, 
        cast(AssignedTo as nvarchar(max)) caption, 
        AssignedTo,
        1 rn
    from tblHierarchy 
    WHERE AssignedTo = 'No More Level'
    union all 
    select t.Person, 
        cast(t.AssignedTo + '|' + c.caption as nvarchar(max)), 
        t.AssignedTo,
        rn +1
    from cte c
    inner join tblHierarchy t on t.AssignedTo = c.Person
)
select concat('|',caption,'|')
from cte 
order by rn desc,concat('|',caption,'|') 
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/44b93/52/0)**:

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is what you're after. you need to use an rCTE to iterate through your dataset, providing details for both the "original" user and their "parent". Then you need to get the "Top 1 per group" for each user, based on the maximum level, as you'll get 1 row per level for a user otherwise. Then, finally, you can filter on the row number:

```sql
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT H.Person,
           H.AssignedTo,
           H.Person AS NextPerson,
           H.AssignedTo AS NextAssignedTo,
           CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),CONCAT('|',H.AssignedTo,'|')) AS ExpectedResult,
           1 AS Level
    FROM dbo.tblHierarchy H
    UNION ALL      
    SELECT r.Person,
           r.AssignedTo,
           H.Person AS NextPerson,
           H.AssignedTo AS NextAssignedTo,
           CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),CONCAT(r.Expectedresult,H.AssignedTo,'|')),
           Level + 1
    FROM dbo.tblHierarchy H
         JOIN rCTE r ON r.NextAssignedTo = H.Person),
RNs AS(
    SELECT r.Person,
           r.AssignedTo,
           r.ExpectedResult,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.Person ORDER BY r.level DESC) AS RN
    FROM rCTE r)
SELECT RN.Person,
       RN.AssignedTo,
       RN.ExpectedResult
FROM RNs RN
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY RN.Person;
```

Note that that the ordering isn't what is in your expected results due to your data type choice. `Person` is an `nvarchar` and so the value `'10'` is **lower** than the value `'2'`, and so all person's with a value starting with `'1'` will be sorted first, then `'2'`, then `'3'`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are after ?

```
with Hierarchy(Person, AssignedTo, Result) as
( select m.Person, m.AssignedTo, convert(varchar(max), m.Person)
  from   tblHierarchy m
    left join tblHierarchy m1 on m.AssignedTo = m1.Person
  where m.AssignedTo = 'No More Level'
  union all
  select d.Person, d.AssignedTo, convert(varchar(max), s.Result + '|' + d.Person)
  from   Hierarchy s
    inner join tblHierarchy d on s.Person = d.AssignedTo
)
select s.Person, s.AssignedTo, s.Result
from   Hierarchy s
order by case when isnumeric(s.Person) = 1 then convert(int, s.Person) else 99999 end
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Try it in this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ee284d824cf480776ccfae28d1490910)

The result is

```
Person  AssignedTo      Result
1       10              CEO|10000|1000|100|10|1
2       20              CEO|20000|2000|200|20|2
3       30              CEO|30000|3000|300|30|3
10      100             CEO|10000|1000|100|10
20      200             CEO|20000|2000|200|20
30      300             CEO|30000|3000|300|30
100     1000            CEO|10000|1000|100
200     2000            CEO|20000|2000|200
300     3000            CEO|30000|3000|300
1000    10000           CEO|10000|1000
2000    20000           CEO|20000|2000
3000    30000           CEO|30000|3000
10000   CEO             CEO|10000
20000   CEO             CEO|20000
30000   CEO             CEO|30000
CEO     No More Level   CEO
```